# How to upload videos (resumably) to Vimeo from a Rails 5 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, vimeo-api

I am trying to upload videos to my Vimeo account from my RoR 5 application using the Vimeo API and the option "Resumable HTTP PUT uploads":

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-http-put-uploads

For this I'm using Paperclip to upload the video to my application and then I want to do a multipart PUT request to send the file with the `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers as the API documentation specifies, but I don't have an idea how to send the video file via PUT request, any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Video uploading is a long task. It is better to run long tasks in a separate process. For that you can use [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) with [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) as the backend. Delayed Job works with the existing database and does not require a separate Redis server.

Enqueue a Vimeo upload job after the video is uploaded (the model is saved). Use the video id as the job parameter. I also assume that Paperclip attribute name is `video`.

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord

  has_attached_file :video

  after_commit :upload_to_vimeo

  def upload_to_vimeo
    VimeoUploadJob.perform_later(id)
  end

end
```

The uploading job should use an HTTP client to work with Vimeo API. You can use [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) from the standard library. Here is an example of its usage. **It is incomplete** and provided for illustration purposes only.

```
class VimeoUploadJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :uploads

  def perform(video_id)
    video = Video.find(video_id)

    http = Net::HTTP.new('api.vimeo.com', 443)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.start do |session|

      # Generate an upload ticket
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/me/videos')
      request.form_data = {'type' => 'streaming'}
      response = session.request(request)
      ticket = OpenStruct.new(JSON.parse(response.body))

      # Upload your video
      request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(ticket.upload_link_secure)
      request.content_type   = video.video_content_type
      request.content_length = video.video_file_size
      request.body_stream    = File.open(video.video.path)
      response = session.request(request)
      if response.code == 501
        # error
      end

      # Verify the upload
      request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(ticket.upload_link_secure)
      request.add_field('Content-Range', 'bytes */*')
      response = session.request(request)
      if response.code == 308
        range = response.range
      end

      # Complete the upload
      request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(ticket.complete_uri)
      response = session.request(request)
      video_uri = response['Location']

    end
  end
end
```

I hope that this explains how to work with the API. You can improve this example until it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!. I am trying to execute your code until verify the upload, but I get a "{"error":"The requested page could not be found"}" response (404). Do you know why this happens ?

Comment: No. You need to understand it yourself. You can `puts` any values you need to see. You can use the `curl` program to make test requests from terminal. We all do this when we work with any API. We explore it.